# Navisworks model slowly loading in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have integrated the Forge Viewer in our web application to upload and view the navisworks model.

We have uploaded the 46MB Navisworks file and successfully uploaded and extract metadata using Forge APIs. We have linked the BIM model with our already available existing assets in the web application.

If we click on the particular asset from the asset tree, the corresponding ObjectID will be passed to the Forge Viewer and then the selected asset will be zoomed and highlighted in the Forge viewer.
This is worked in faster if we host the web application in our internal server.
**But the issue is: If we host the same web application in client environment server machine, the application works fine. But if we click on the any asset, the loading time of the selected asset in Forge Viewer is taking too long. The Zooming time also taking too long. We are not able to Zoom In/Out in faster manner.**

Kindly help us to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The application hosted on the server should not impact what happens on the client. The Viewer is a WEB component (client side), and loads content from the Autodesk server, so should not be different either. Are you using the same client machine in both cases? the graphic cards may have an impact, but nowadays it would be surprising unless you run a a very low end client machine like a cell phone. I would need more details to understands what's going on.

Comment: Did anybody find solution of it. Please revert me. Me also facing same issue of slow bim model loadings.